# scrolltop not working inside iframe in ios mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iframe

I have a div and iframe, iframe refers to outer website (ex: google.com).

```
<iframe class='my-profile-display' src="www.google.com"></iframe>

$('.my-profile-display').contents().animate({ scrollTop : 100 });
```

1. when google loaded in my dev, iframe content should scroll to top (animate.scrolltop) automatically(till search bar - i.e. search bar should show on the top) while loading the screen.

I have gone through many of the posts, none of them were seems working.. Can any body help us on this..

This is only on ios mobile and ipad.. no other places, ever where else working absolutely fine.

Thanks,

Comment: Could be a race condition? Have you tried like `$('.my-profile-display').on('load', function() {  $(this).contents.animate({'scrollTop': 100});  });`

Comment: I found the solution. IOS stand alone, $(html,body) will not recognize overflow:auto option, , so we should manually set overflow-y:scroll in iframe content. It works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @KarthikNerella I'm having the same problem. Do you mean making it <iframe style="overflow-y:scroll"> ? That doesn't work for me